# What is the solution if cpanel does not support event scheduler for shared hosting?

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting

Can someone suggest a solution for Event Scheduler on phpmyadmin. As I have Shared hosting and it does not support Event Scheduler for shared hosting. Is there another way to make the feature working like events????

Comment: You could schedule your PC instead to access a specific page that will trigger the event in the host, or make your website check if it is supposed to run events on every access.

Comment: Can you please provide a link or give a description on how to do it??

Comment: Got the solution. We can do the same using Cron jobs....